# Print a list that contains Chinese characters in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages, gbk

My code looks like :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print ["asdf", "中文"]
print ["中文"]
print "中文"
```

The output in the Eclipse console is very strange:

```
['asdf', '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87']
['\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87']
中文
```

My first question is: **why did the last line get the correct output, and the others didn't?**

And my second question is: **how do I correct the wrong ones** (to make them output real characters instead of the code that begins with "x") **?**

Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 6):

> why did the last line get the correct output, and the others didn't?

When you `print foo`, what gets printed out is `str(foo)`.

However, if `foo` is a `list`, `str(foo)` uses `repr(bar)` for each element `bar`, not `str(bar)`.

The `str` of a string is the string itself; the `repr` of a string is the string inside quotes, and escaped.

> how do I correct the wrong ones

If you want to print the `str` of every element in a `list`, you have to do that explicitly. For example:

```
print '[' + ', '.join(["asdf", "中文"]) + ']'
```

---

There have been sporadic proposals to change this behavior, so `str` on a sequence calls `str` on its members. [PEP 3140](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3140/) is the rejected proposal. [This thread from 2009](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-ideas/20009/) explains the design rationale behind rejecting it.

But primarily, it's either so these don't print the same thing:

```
a = 'foo, bar'
b = 'foo'
c = 'bar'
print [a]
print [b, c]
```

Or, paraphrasing Ned Batchelder: `repr` is always for geeks; `str` is for humans when possible, but printing lists with their brackets and commas is already for geeks.

Comment: Also, checkout this very detailed explanation of the differences between str and repr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Comment: But in Python2, `>>> str('中文')` will return  `'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'` but not `"中文"` as `print("中文")`.

Comment: @SiminJie No, `str('中文')` _returns_ `'中文'`, because it's already a `str`, so calling `str` on it does nothing. Which does happen to be the exact same string as `'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'` if your source encoding is UTF-8, but it will never _print_ backslash-escaped. But if you just evaluate a value at the interactive interpreter, the interpreter displays the `repr` of that value, not the value itself.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are using the `__repr__` of the strings, the last one is using the `__str__` method

You could use

```
print ", ".join(["asdf", "中文"])
```